# Binding MapCenter coordinates: Center is null

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, dictionary, windows-phone-8

I have Jeff Wilcox static map control:

```
<jwMaps:StaticMap
            VerticalAlignment="Top"                                   
            Margin="-12,0,-12,0"
            Provider="Bing"                                    
            Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
            Height="200"
            ZoomLevel="1"
            Visibility="Visible"
            MapCenter="{Binding Coordinates}" />
```

But I have error `System.ArgumentException: Center is null`. How can I set default coordinates in this case?  Coordinates has `GeoCoordinate` type.

Answer (score 0):

put it by code 
add name attribute to the StaticMap example Name="staticMap"
then staticMap.MapCenter=Coordinates;

Comment: Of course it will work. :) But I wanted to make it through the data-binding. The ViewModel should not know anything about the View.